# File in Pub Directory Not Updating in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cache, pub

I have updated a **.js** file in **pub** directory and run cache:flush. But when I open **website/filename.js** in browser and incognito browser, it still load the old file. The permission to pub directory is already 777. I have also run cache:clean, setup:upgrade, di:compile, and static-content-deploy but still load the old file.

Comment: Please remove the manually pub/static and run the all commands

Comment: you mean just remove static folder and run setup:upgrade, di:compile, and static-content:deploy?

Comment: Yes remove van run commands